# Strange output on Woocommerce title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Why in Woocommerce the following code:

```
if ( is_product_category() ) :
    $titolo = woocommerce_page_title();
    echo '<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title" >' .$titolo. '</h1>';
endif;
```

produces this output:

```
"This is the title"
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `woocommerce_page_title()` is set to `echo` the page title. Try `$titolo = woocommerce_page_title(false);`

See: [WooCommerce_page_title reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_page_title.html)